# custom callout view get error while using library from git

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, callout

Lib URL: github.com/s3lvin/DXCustomCallout-ObjC

i used above link library for my iOS custom callout view and i am not able to use following class in my project. getting error

```
DXAnnotationSettings.h
DXAnnotationSettings.m
DXAnnotationView.m
DXAnnotationView.h
```

Error is :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DXAnnotation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_DXAnnotationSettings, _OBJC_CLASS_$_DXAnnotationView )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

error snapshout is available at following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4g9xpd9htmoejur/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-19%20at%206.19.34%20PM.png?dl=0

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

HI i also get the same error  i just add 2 Lines in the bottom and able to fix this issue

```
@end

@implementation DXAnnotation
```

Check screenshot . [image]